# ios8 AVAudioEngine: proper way to play multiple (long) audio files

Tags: objective-c, ios8, core-audio

I'm attempting to play several fairly long files at once in sync using `AVAudioEngine` in iOS 8.

I can do this with the following:

```
- (void)startAudio {

    AVAudioMixerNode *mainMixer = [self.engine mainMixerNode];

    AVAudioPlayerNode *player = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
    AVAudioPlayerNode *player2 = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
    AVAudioPlayerNode *player3 = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];

    [self.engine attachNode:player];
    [self.engine attachNode:player2];
    [self.engine attachNode:player3];

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], @"file1.caf"];
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];
    AVAudioFile *file = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:fileUrl error:nil];

    NSString *fileName2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], @"file2.caf"];
    NSURL *fileUrl2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName2];
    AVAudioFile *file2 = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:fileUrl2 error:nil];

    NSString *fileName3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], @"file3.caf"];
    NSURL *fileUrl3 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName3];
    AVAudioFile *file3 = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:fileUrl3 error:nil];

    [self.engine connect:player to:mainMixer format:file.processingFormat];
    [self.engine connect:player2 to:mainMixer format:file2.processingFormat];
    [self.engine connect:player3 to:mainMixer format:file3.processingFormat];

    [player scheduleFile:file atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];
    [player2 scheduleFile:file2 atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];
    [player3 scheduleFile:file3 atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];

    NSError *error;
    [self.engine startAndReturnError:&error];
    [player play];
    [player2 play];
    [player3 play];
}
```

But that seems cumbersome. I thought there is a way to chain nodes together, but I can't find any examples and wasn't quite clear how to do this from watching the WWDC session on `AVAudioEngine`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should not atTime:nil, but choose a time in the near future. Like now + 0.1 seconds and schedule it all players to play at that time.

Look at my question an answer at: [Scheduling an audio file for playback in the future with AVAudioTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604831/scheduling-an-audio-file-for-playback-in-the-future-with-avaudiotime/31657336#31657336)
to find out how. 
scheduleSegment or scheduleFile work about the same way, but with scheduleSegment you can start playing at any point in the file.

Comment: Don't mind starting ***atTime:nil*** - anyways the system isn't going to start you
until the next render frame in the future (1024 samples) - even if you start ***atTime:player.lastRenderTime***. No delay value is required unless you really want your player to get started later in the future... - delaying doesn't change anything in the accuracy of the synchronization behavior - provided that it is done correctly!!!

Comment: The point is that if you want to start multiple players at once, they need to start at exactly the same time. It can happen that 1 of the players is started in a later frame then the others, creating an audible delay. So you should start the players in the future. At the time of writing my previous answer, I didn't know of player.lastRenderTime, but keep in mind that you need to use player.lastRenderTime from the first player, to schedule all players.

Comment: Definitely true - but AVAudioPlayerNode is a little more subtle due to flaws in Apple's design. I would even call them bugs. Note that the original post is talking of synchronized ***PLAYING*** and not synchronized ***STARTING***!!! That makes a big difference due to this bug in the AVAudioEngine. By using player.lastRenderTime you are already dead in questions of sync'ed ***playing*** because lastRenderTime is a time stamp of the past and you are actually not playing *atTime:* in the future like you suggest but rather in the past. The system reschedules you and now you are screwed...

Answer (score 1):

ATTENTION - Note the difference between synchronized ***STARTING*** and synchronized ***PLAYING***!!!

If you only want to start several player **ONCE** and at the same start time you definitely have to use the *playAtTime:* method with all of them referring to the same ***now*** time that you can freely choose. You can choose ***nil*** as a value and the system will schedule them on the next render frame 1024 samples later. Just in case you don't have your playAtTime: calls in a row (which you do have with *play:* in your code above) but rather interrupted by some other calls or NSLog-s it is generally safer to assign a start time instead of just putting ***nil***. But mind you this only gives you a sync'ed **FIRST** start but no further guaranty for synching additional new players to the block of players recently started.

There are some design flaws on Apple's side (I would call them bugs) that make sync'ed playing with AVAudioEngine almost impossible. e.g.

- if your start time is ***playAtTime:playerLastRender*** you are already screwed. Your player DO start in-sync to each other but you are already out-of-sync in regards to your engine's node time because...
- in some cases your submitted start time gets overruled and changed by the system, so all subsequent calculations - you have to do for e.g. synching an additional player - that are based on your own requested (but silently changed under the hood) start time will be out-of-sync...
- the system even goofs itself up!!! ***playerTimeForNodeTime:*** and ***nodeTimeForPlayerTime:*** do report wrong values - so you can't make any decisions based on these values either etc.

For the subtleties have a look at my answer in

[AVAudioEngine multiple AVAudioInputNodes do not play in perfect sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316322/avaudioengine-multiple-avaudioinputnodes-do-not-play-in-perfect-sync/37603167#37603167)

I've covered a lot of stuff of AVAudioEngine that one should know!

Have fun!