# AVAudioEngine multiple AVAudioInputNodes do not play in perfect sync

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, core-audio

I've been trying to use AVAudioEngine to schedule multiple audio files to play in perfect sync, but when listening to the output there seems to be a very slight delay between input nodes. The audio engine is implemented using the following graph:

```
//
//AVAudioPlayerNode1 -->
//AVAudioPlayerNode2 -->
//AVAudioPlayerNode3 --> AVAudioMixerNode --> AVAudioUnitVarispeed ---> AvAudioOutputNode
//AVAudioPlayerNode4 -->                                            |
//AVAudioPlayerNode5 -->                                        AudioTap
//      |                                                         
//AVAudioPCMBuffers    
//
```

And I am using the following code to load the samples and schedule them at the same time:

```
- (void)scheduleInitialAudioBlock:(SBScheduledAudioBlock *)block {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        NSString *path = [self assetPathForChannel:i trackItem:block.trackItem]; //this fetches the right audio file path to be played
        AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer = [self bufferFromFile:path];
        [block.buffers addObject:buffer];
    }

    AVAudioTime *time = [[AVAudioTime alloc] initWithSampleTime:0 atRate:1.0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        [inputNodes[i] scheduleBuffer:block.buffers[i]
                                   atTime:time
                                  options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferInterrupts
                        completionHandler:nil];
    }
}

- (AVAudioPCMBuffer *)bufferFromFile:(NSString *)filePath {
    NSURL *fileURl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioFile *audioFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:fileURl commonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32 interleaved:NO error:&error];
    if (error) {
        return nil;
    }

    AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:audioFile.processingFormat frameCapacity:audioFile.length];
    [audioFile readIntoBuffer:buffer frameCount:audioFile.length error:&error];

    if (error) {
        return nil;
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

I've noticed the issue is only perceivable on devices, I'm testing with an iPhone5s, but I cannot figure out why the audio files are playing out of sync, any help would be greatly appreciated.

** ANSWER **

We ended up sorting the issue with the following code:

```
AVAudioTime *startTime = nil;

for (AVAudioPlayerNode *node in inputNodes) {
    if(startTime == nil) {
        const float kStartDelayTime = 0.1; // sec
        AVAudioFormat *outputFormat = [node outputFormatForBus:0];
        AVAudioFramePosition startSampleTime = node.lastRenderTime.sampleTime + kStartDelayTime * outputFormat.sampleRate;
        startTime = [AVAudioTime timeWithSampleTime:startSampleTime atRate:outputFormat.sampleRate];
    }

    [node playAtTime:startTime];
}
```

This gave each AVAudioInputNode enough time to load the buffers and fixed all our audio syncing issues. Hope this helps others!

Comment: Well, you have multiple player nodes and on each one you need to call `play` method. My guess is that this call immediately starts processing and throwing stuff at audio thread. As each `play` is called at different time it's probably causing this delay. Whether my reasoning is correct and whether you can launch player nodes in a batch I don't know. I'm actually using Apple developer support ticket in which I asked similar question. If I get any definite answer I will get back to this question.

Comment: The problem is not the ***playAt:*** method at all. It is exactly meant for batch launching. You just have to use one concrete anchor time. See my answer below...

Comment: So despite your solution in ANSWER your problem will remain if a device takes more than 0.1 secs for getting its act together. These are magic numbers as long as you don't schedule them correctly...

Comment: Hi, Danny, My goal is to play AVAudioPlayerNode from specified time. I get buffer, and scheduling buffer at time, and then calling playat time method. player does not play from specified time. Instead it play from start.

Comment: Should I need to schedule buffer every time I play ?

Answer (score 17):

***Problem:***

Well, the problem is that you retrieve your ***player.lastRenderTime*** in every run of the for-loop before ***playAt:***

> So, you'll actually get a different ***now***-time for every player!

The way *you* do it you might as well start all player in the loop with ***play:*** or ***playAtTime:nil*** !!! You would experience the same result with a loss of sync...

For the same reason your player run out-of-sync in different ways on different devices, depending on the speed of the machine ;-) Your ***now***-times are random magic numbers - so, don't assume they will always work if they just happen to work in your scenario. Even the smallest delay because of a busy run loop or CPU will throw you out-of-sync again...

***Solution:***

What you really have to do is to get ***ONE*** discrete snapshot of ***now = player.lastRenderTime*** before the loop and use this very same anchor in order to get a batched synchronized start for all your player.

This way you do not even need to delay your player's start. Admittedly, the system will clip some of the leading frames - (but of course the same amount for every player ;-) - to compensate for the difference between your recently set ***now*** (which is actually already in the past and gone) and the actual ***playTime*** (which still lies ahead in the very near future) but eventually start all your player exactly in-sync as if you actually had really started them at ***now*** in the past. These clipped frames are almost never noticeable and you'll have peace of mind regarding to responsiveness...

If you happen to need these frames - because of audible clicks or artifacts at file/segment/buffer start -  well, shift your ***now*** to the future by starting your player delayed. But of course you'll get this little lag after hitting the start button - although of course still in perfect sync...

***Conclusion:***

The point here is to have one single reference ***now***-time for all player and to call your ***playAtTime:now*** methods as soon as possible after capturing this ***now***-reference. The bigger the gap the bigger the portion of clipped leading frames will be - unless you provide a reasonable start-delay and add it to your ***now***-time, which of course causes unresponsiveness in form of a delayed start after hitting your start button.

And always be aware of the fact that - whatever delay on whatever device is produced by the audio buffering mechanisms - it ***DOESN'T*** effect the synchronicity of any amount of player if done in the proper, above described way! It ***DOESN'T*** delay your audio, either! Just the window that actually lets you hear your audio gets opened at a later point in time...

---

***Be advised that:***

- If you go for the ***un-delayed*** (*super-responsive*) ***start option*** and
  for whatever reason happen to produce a big delay (*between the
  capturing of **now** and the actual start of your player*), you will
  clip-off a big leading portion (up to about ~300ms/0.3sec) of your
  audio. This means when you start your player it will start right away
  but not resume from the position you recently paused it but rather
  (up to ~300ms) later in your audio. So the acoustic perception is that
  pause-play cuts out a portion of your audio on the go although everything is perfectly in-sync.
- As the start delay that you provide in the ***playAtTime:now +
  myProvidedDelay*** method call is a fixed constant value (that doesn't get
  dynamically adjusted to accommodate buffering delay or other varying
  parameters at heavy system load) even going for the ***Delayed Option***
  with a provided delay time smaller than about ~300ms can cause a
  clipping of leading audio-samples if the device-dependent preparation
  time exceeds your provided delay time.
- The maximum amount of clipping does (by design) not get bigger than
  these ~300ms. To get prove just force a controlled (sample-accurate) clipping
  of leading frames by e.g. adding a negative delay-time to ***now***
  and you will perceive a growing clipped audio-portion by augmenting this
  negative value. Every negative value that is bigger then ~300ms gets
  rectified to ~300ms. So a provided negative delay of 30 seconds will
  lead to the same behavior as a negative value of 10, 6, 3 or 1
  seconds, and of course also including negative 0.8, 0.5 seconds down
  to ~0.3

This examples serves well for demonstration purposes but negative delay values shouldn't be used in production code.

---

***ATTENTION:***

The most important thing of all in a multi-player setup is to keep your ***player.pause*** in sync. There is still no synchronized exit strategy in AVAudioPlayerNode as of June 2016.

Just a little method look-up or logging out something to the console in-between two ***player.pause*** calls could force the latter one to be executed one or even more frame/sample(s) later than the former one. So your player wouldn't actually stop at the same relative position in time. And above all - different devices would yield different behavior...

If you now start them in the above mentioned (sync'ed) manner, these out-of-sync current player positions of your last pause will definitely get force-sync'ed to your new ***now***-position at every playAtTime: - which essentially means that you are propagating the lost sample/frame(s) into the future with every new start of your player. This of course adds up with every new start/pause cycle and widens the gap. Do this fifty or hundred times and you already get a nice delay effect without using an effect-audio-unit ;-)

As we don't have any (by the system provided) control over this factor the only remedy is to put all calls to ***player.pause*** straight one after the other in a tight sequence without anything in-between them, like you can see in the examples below. Don't throw them in a for-loop or anything similar - this would be a guaranty for ending up out-of-sync at the next pause/start of your player...

Whether keeping these calls together is a 100% perfect solution or the run-loop under any big CPU load could by chance interfere and force-separate the pause calls from each other and cause frame drops - I don't know - at least in weeks messing around with the AVAudioNode API I could in no way force my multi-player-set to get out-of-sync - however, I still don't feel very comfy or safe with this un-synchronized, *random-magic-number* pause solution...

---

***Code-example and alternative:***

If your engine is already running you got a ***@property lastRenderTime*** in AVAudioNode - your player's superclass - This is your ticket to 100% sample-frame accurate sync...

```
AVAudioFormat *outputFormat = [playerA outputFormatForBus:0];

const float kStartDelayTime = 0.0; // seconds - in case you wanna delay the start

AVAudioFramePosition now = playerA.lastRenderTime.sampleTime;

AVAudioTime *startTime = [AVAudioTime timeWithSampleTime:(now + (kStartDelayTime * outputFormat.sampleRate)) atRate:outputFormat.sampleRate];

[playerA playAtTime: startTime];
[playerB playAtTime: startTime];
[playerC playAtTime: startTime];
[playerD playAtTime: startTime];

[player...
```

---

By the way - you can achieve the same 100% sample-frame accurate result with the AVAudioPlayer/AVAudioRecorder classes...

```
NSTimeInterval startDelayTime = 0.0; // seconds - in case you wanna delay the start
NSTimeInterval now = playerA.deviceCurrentTime;

NSTimeIntervall startTime = now + startDelayTime;

[playerA playAtTime: startTime];
[playerB playAtTime: startTime];
[playerC playAtTime: startTime];
[playerD playAtTime: startTime];

[player...
```

---

With no startDelayTime the first 100-200ms of all players will get clipped off because the start command actually takes its time to the run loop although the players have already started (well, been scheduled) 100% in sync at **now**. But with a ***startDelayTime = 0.25*** you are good to go. And never forget to **prepareToPlay** your players in advance so that at start time no additional buffering or setup has to be done - just starting them guys ;-)

Comment: I use your snapshotting technique (single `lastCurrentTime` value) to start multiple `AVAudioPlayerNode`s in sync. However seems that playback is delayed by about ~250 ms. Any ideas ?

Comment: First of all, great answer. Are you still active on Stack Overflow? I'm having difficulties with this exact problem. Your answer has led me to the right direction, but I need those first ~200 ms of audio and they still are getting cut off. Could you help out?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘still are getting cut off...’ - ‘still’ despite of what? Despite of setting a kStartDelayTime?

Comment: But `startTime` is different for each player, as each player has its own `lastRenderTime`.
One more thing I do not understand is `deviceCurrentTime` — can't find such property.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks you!

Answer (score 3):

I used Apple developer support ticket for my own problems with AVAudioEngine in which one problem was (is) exactly the same as yours. I got this code to try:

```
AudioTimeStamp myAudioQueueStartTime = {0};
UInt32 theNumberOfSecondsInTheFuture = 5;
Float64 hostTimeFreq = CAHostTimeBase::GetFrequency();
UInt64 startHostTime = CAHostTimeBase::GetCurrentTime()+theNumberOfSecondsInTheFuture*hostTimeFreq;
myAudioQueueStartTime.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampHostTimeValid;
myAudioQueueStartTime.mHostTime = startHostTime;
AVAudioTime *time = [AVAudioTime timeWithAudioTimeStamp:&myAudioQueueStartTime sampleRate:_file.processingFormat.sampleRate];
```

Aside from scheduling play in Skynet era instead of 5 seconds in the future, it still didn't sync two AVAudioPlayerNodes (when I switched `GetCurrentTime()` for some arbitrary value to actually manage to play the nodes).

So not being able to sync two and more nodes together is a bug (confirmed by Apple support). Generally, if you don't have to use something that was introduced with AVAudioEngine (and you don't know how to translate it into AUGraph), I advise to use AUGraph instead. It's a bit more overhead to implement but you have more control over it.

Comment: We ended up sorting the issue with the following code:

    `AVAudioTime *startTime = nil;
    
    for (AVAudioPlayerNode *node in inputNodes) {
        if(startTime == nil) {
            const float kStartDelayTime = 0.1; // sec
            AVAudioFormat *outputFormat = [node outputFormatForBus:0];
            AVAudioFramePosition startSampleTime = node.lastRenderTime.sampleTime + kStartDelayTime * outputFormat.sampleRate;
            startTime = [AVAudioTime timeWithSampleTime:startSampleTime atRate:outputFormat.sampleRate];
        }
        
        [node playAtTime:startTime];
    }`

Comment: Instead of playing all AVInputNodes together, I scheduled them 0.1 seconds in the future allowing enough times for the buffers to load on each channel. This sorted out the issue.

Comment: The problem is not the ***playAt:*** method at all. It is exactly meant for batch launching. You just have to use one concrete anchor time. See my answer below...

Comment: @DannyBravo - Your problem will remain if a device takes more than 0.1 secs for getting its act together. These are magic numbers as long as you don't schedule them correctly...